# How to autofocus already joined channels in irssi with /join?

Tags: irc, irssi, focus

I've got a bunch of windows (>80) in irssi. Quite often I quickly want to switch the active window to #channelX, without knowing which window number it has. Cycling through all of them is useless too of course. I'm not sure where to find the answer, named windows?

I messed with autofocus_new_items and window_auto_change but both don't cut it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the script `windows_switcher` from [web::irssi::scripts](http://scripts.irssi.org/)

Download the `perl` file and put it in `~/.irssi/scripts/autorun/`.

This is the short help contained in the file itself:

```
# Usage:
# * Add the statusbar item:
#   /STATUSBAR window add window_switcher
# * Type /ws followed by a window number or part of a window or channel name.
# * When the right item is at the first place in the statusbar, press enter.
# * For faster usage, do "/BIND ^G multi erase_line;insert_text /ws ",
#    type ctrl-G, and start typing...
```

In particular you can write `/ws` followed by a partial channel name to switch to that channel.